# KendoUI grid - how to make it not overflow, while inside a tab strip?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Following this example - http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html, I have a grid and a tab strip inside the grid.  One of the tabs has a grid within.  This table is rather long, so I had to add a scrollbar.  The grid overflows - though the scrollbar works, the data spills on to the next row, making the whole thing look ugly.

Is there any way to make the inner grid (the one within the tabstrip) not overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this. Your parent has to grow to accommodate the last row. You can try placing the grid in a parent element and add a padding to the grid parent while setting the overflow to auto.